# How to , in excel, change the value of cell Y from cell X, while only typing in cell X

Tags: excel, function

In Excel, is there any way to write a function in cell A1 that sets the value of B2 to 5. I need to do this without inputting any function or reference into cell B2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, a formula or function cannot change the value of another cell.  you will need a sub in vba to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use formulas in column B?

Answer (score 2):

In **A1** enter the formula:

```
=A2
```

and in the worksheet code area, enter the following Event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("A1").Value = 5 Then Range("B2").Value = 5
End Sub
```

Now if you enter a **5** into cell **A2**, it will also get entered into cell **B2**

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**